Switching from CJS to ESM/ES6 & Electron/React app renders and loads in dev environment, but not in production, but paths log correctly to asar
I recently updated my application from CJS to ESM and it works completely fine in development, but when in production, it launches the Window, but doesn't render anything and I've been banging my head trying to figure out why, so I'm hoping someone in the overflow community would know. When in production, if my project directory is stored locally in the Desktop, it launches the application fine, but whenever I drag the directory from the Desktop to Downloads, it just loads the Window with no react components and the devtools doesn't open. I've also logged the paths that the app is using in production and the path is correctly pointing to the app.asar and it also fetches the iconPath perfectly fine, but that's the only thing it shows. Below I included my main.js, webpack.config.js, and my package.json settings. I've went through each individual file and made sure it correctly uses import/export, I also made sure to use libraries that support ESM/ES6, and I've also tried commenting out everything and isolated the main.js and all .jsx components and it still has the problem of not rendering anything in production without the project directory and rendering perfectly fine in development.
main.js
import os from 'os';
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname, join } from 'path';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import electronUpdater from 'electron-updater';
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import createColorizedLogger from '../../Modules/Functions/logger.js';

let mainWindow = null;
const isDevelopment = !app.isPackaged;
const basePath = isDevelopment 
    ? join(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), '../../build')
    : join(dirname(app.getAppPath()), 'app.asar', 'build');

const preloadPath = join(basePath, "preload.mjs");
const indexPath = `file://${join(basePath, "index.html")}`;
const iconPath = join(basePath, "e23ba570b8d41f58cf6c57954a6cad57.png");


const renderWindow = async () => {
    const userHomeDirectory = os.homedir();
    const applicationDirectory = join(userHomeDirectory, 'Tools Application');
    const settingsPath = join(applicationDirectory, 'settings.json');

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1400,
        height: 800,
        minWidth: 1400,
        minHeight: 800,
        frame: false,
        backgroundColor: '#0E0F16',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            webSecurity: false,
            allowRunningInsecureContent: true,
            sandbox: false,
            preload: preloadPath
        },
        icon: iconPath,
        resizable: false
    });

    await discordRpc();
    await userDatabaseConnection();
    const logger = await createColorizedLogger(uuidv4());
    logger.info(iconPath);
    logger.info(indexPath);
    logger.info(preloadPath);

    mainWindow.setMenu(null);
    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        decidePageToLoad(mainWindow);
    });

    try {
        mainWindow.loadURL(`${indexPath}#/`);
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }
    
    mainWindow.on("ready-to-show", () => {
        mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
    });

    ipcMain.on('validate-license', (event, inputLicenseKey) => {
        validateLicenseHandler(event, inputLicenseKey, mainWindow);
    });
};

app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-gpu-blacklist');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
app.whenReady().then(async () => {
    process.env.ELECTRON_DISABLE_SECURITY_WARNINGS = 'true';
    await renderWindow();
});

ipcMain.on('close-main-window', () => {
    if (mainWindow) {
        mainWindow.close();
    };
});

ipcMain.on('minimize-main-window', () => {
    if (mainWindow) {
        mainWindow.minimize();
    };
});

ipcMain.on('close-update-window', () => {
    if (updateWin) {
        updateWin.close();
    };
});

const getMainWindow = () => mainWindow;
const main = {
    getMainWindow: getMainWindow,
};

export default main;

webpack.config.js
import webpack from 'webpack';
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { dirname, join } from "path";
import HtmlWebPackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

const electronConfig = {
  entry: './src/main/main.js',
  name: 'electron',
  target: 'electron-main',
  /* externals: [nodeExternals()], */
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".*", ".mjs",".js",".json"],
    alias: {
      'snappy': false,
      '@mongodb-js/zstd': false
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, '/build'),
    publicPath: '',
    filename: 'app.js',
    chunkFormat: 'module',
    module: true,
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: []
};

const preloadConfig = {
  entry: './src/preload/preload.mjs',
  target: 'electron-preload',
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, '/build'),
    filename: 'preload.mjs',
    chunkFormat: 'module',
    module: true,
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".js", ".json"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
};

const reactConfig = {
  entry: './src/renderer/index.js',
  name: 'react',
  target: 'electron-renderer',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ['babel-loader']
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".mjs", ".*", ".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".css", ".svg"],
  },
  output: {
    path: join(__dirname, '/build'),
    publicPath: './',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    module: true,
    chunkFormat: 'module',
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: join(__dirname, '/build/'),
    },
    compress: true
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/renderer/index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      global: 'window'
    })
  ]
};

export default [electronConfig, reactConfig, preloadConfig];

package.json
  "scripts": {
    "electron": "electron --trace-warnings ./build/app.js",
    "webpack": "webpack --mode production",
    "build-win": "electron-builder build --win -c.extraMetadata.main=./build/app.js --publish never"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Tools Application",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.ToolsApplication",
    "productName": "Tools Application",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "extraResources": [
      "worker.exe",
      "decline.wav",
      "success.wav"
    ],
    "publish": [
      {
        "provider": "spaces",
        "name": "application",
        "region": "nyc3"
      }
    ],
    "win": {
      "icon": "./src/renderer/Images/icon.ico",
      "target": "nsis"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "./src/renderer/Images/icon.ico",
      "uninstallerIcon": "./src/renderer/Images/icon.ico",
      "oneClick": false,
      "allowToChangeInstallationDirectory": true
    }
  }

